# Was Hippolyta telling the truth about Diana's origin?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

At the start of *Wonder Woman*, we see Diana's "mother", Hippolyta, tell Diana that she was made out of clay and given life by Zeus. This is repeated by Diana at least once.

We later learn;

> That Diana herself, rather than the sword she wields, is the Godkiller, the weapon designed to defeat Ares. At this point, she starts calling Ares her brother.

Because of this, I began to assume that Hippolyta had lied, and that Zeus was actually her natural father and Hippolyta her natural mother. However, as a friend pointed out later, the film never explicitly confirms this - the "twist" still works if she's still made from clay, which was the origin of Diana in the comics for a very long time.

Is there any evidence in the film itself, or any statement been made from the people who worked on *Wonder Woman*, that definitely answers the question of "Is Diana Prince the natural born daughter of Zeus and Hippolyta, or was she really made from clay and bought to life"?

Comment: "Natural father" yeah good one.

Answer (score 6):

> "But in 2011 Diana got a different story (I told you they are always changing) and it’s this origin that the new film decided to co-opt. In the New 52 relaunch of Wonder Woman created by writer Brian Azzarello and artist Cliff Chiang, Diana finds out her mother lied to her. She was not born from a lump of clay (go figure!), but rather the result of an affair between Hippolyta and Zeus. In other words, she’s not merely a gifted Amazon, she’s a full-fledged demigod."-[Vanity Fair](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/06/wonder-woman-movie-easter-egg-father-zeus-clay-bondage)

And

> "The producers had let it slip in the very beginning that the DCEU would most likely be following her New 52 origins as Zeus’s daughter, and director Patty Jenkins more recently teased Diana’s “secret” superpower granted as a result. It didn’t take us long to theorize that Wonder Woman can now use Zeus’s lightning… but that’s just the beginning of her new, demigod superpowers." [-Screen Rant](http://screenrant.com/wonder-woman-movie-2017-powers-explained/)

I don't remember it being explicitly stated in the film that she is in fact the daughter of Zeus, but she does seem to come to the conclusion that she is. It seems that the audience is meant to think this as well. Every article I've read or discussion I've listened to also makes the assumption that she is Zeus' daughter. If this wasn't the case I imagine there would have been a clarifying statement from people attached to the movie or Warner Bros. by now. Some articles mention that it was essentially confirmed by the director and/or producers of the film that the New 52 origin is what they were drawing from but they don't provide citation for this claim.

Comment: So Zeus didn't create Diana for beating Ares but just another of his love children?

Comment: Maybe. I Don't know, sorry.